# Hi, I am trying to change the value of gridview column in cellvalue changed event but i am not getting correct output each time an occured

Tags: c#, winforms, events, gridview

I have three columns Sold QTY ,Return QTY and Transaction QTY now i want to change the value of Sold QTY by subtracting Return QTY from Sold QTY and put the result in SoldQTY column.
Following is my code which i have tried

```
        private void dgvSalesItem_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
         {
            if (dgvSalesItem.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                int counter;
                double SoldQTY = 0;
                double reutrnQTY = 0;
                double TPrice = 0;
                double resultant = 0;


                string PID = dgvSalesItem.CurrentRow.Cells["Column9"].Value.ToString();
                if (dgvSalesItem.CurrentRow.Cells["Column11"].Value != null)
                {
                    SoldQTY = clsCN.num_repl(dgvSalesItem.CurrentRow.Cells["Column11"].Value.ToString());
                }
                if (dgvSalesItem.CurrentRow.Cells["dgvtxtSoldQTY"].Value != null)
                {
                    reutrnQTY = clsCN.num_repl(dgvSalesItem.CurrentRow.Cells["dgvtxtSoldQTY"].Value.ToString());
                }
                if (dgvSalesItem.CurrentRow.Cells["Column12"].Value != null)
                {
                    TPrice = clsCN.num_repl(dgvSalesItem.CurrentRow.Cells["Column12"].Value.ToString());
                }
                if (!(reutrnQTY > SoldQTY))
                {
                    resultant = SoldQTY - reutrnQTY;
                }
                dgvSalesItem.CurrentRow.Cells["Column12"].Value = resultant;


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your life would be a lot easier of you bind your DataGridView to a DataTable and then use the Expression property of the DataColumn to calculate your sum

Example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("SoldQty", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("ReturnQty", typeof(int));

//i'd just do the sum, not bother with the IF bit
dt.Columns.Add("ResultQty", typeof(int)).Expression = "[SoldQty] - [ReturnQty]";

//but you can do this if you really want to only calc when sold>return
dt.Columns.Add("ResultQty", typeof(int)).Expression = "IIF([SoldQty] > [ReturnQty], [SoldQty] - [ReturnQty], 0)";

datagridviewWhatever.DataSource = dt;
```

See [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0) for more info on what you can do with computed columns (expressions)

Comment: Ok ,But is there any solution to perform the above calclulations using CellvalueChanged event and without using data table